# Python threading and passing references

Tags: python, multithreading

How do I pass a reference to the instantiation (self?) of the class.  I'm still learning Python and have not figured this out yet.

I have two alarms, and want to make them automatic, running continuously in the background.  If I could make some calls to them to perform some actions, that would be great.

Basically, why doesn't this work?

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class alarm:

    def __init__(self, interval):
        self.activated = False
        self.sound = "Beeeep"
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        # this runs forever
        while True:
            if self.activated:
                print(self.sound)
            else:
                print("(quiet)")
            sleep(self.interval)

    def on(self):
        self.activated = True

    def off(self):
        self.activated = False

    def set_beep(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound


def main():

    a1 = alarm(.5)
    a2 = alarm(.5)

    print("Waiting 3 secs")
    sleep(3)
    print("Turning on alarm1")
    a1.on

    sleep(2)
    print("Turning on alarm2")
    a2.on

    sleep(2)
    print("Turning off alarms")
    a1.off
    a2.off

    print("Waiting 10 seconds")
    sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is:

(quiet)
(quiet)
Waiting 3 secs
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)
Turning on alarm1
(quiet)
(quiet)
(quiet)

It won't turn on either alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are not calling the methods "on" and "off", to call a method you have to insert a pair of parentheses after it with any arguments inside.

```
def main():

a1 = alarm(.5)
a2 = alarm(.5)

print("Waiting 3 secs")
sleep(3)
print("Turning on alarm1")
a1.on()

sleep(2)
print("Turning on alarm2")
a2.on()

sleep(2)
print("Turning off alarms")
a1.off()
a2.off()

print("Waiting 10 seconds")
sleep(10)
```

Comment: By "round brackets" do you mean parentheses?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I'm not English

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  That was it!

Comment: @ltd9938 Otherwise known as round brackets... just like braces are also known as curly brackets..., even [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) lists them as brackets before calling them parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the functions with a1.on and a1.off, just assigning them to nothing.
For further clarification,

```
a1.on is basically "" = a1.on
```

if you were to type for instance:

```
a = a1.on
```

Then it assigns the function a1.on to a, so:

```
a()
```

Would then execute the function, which is the same as

```
a1.on()
```

So:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class alarm:
    def __init__(self, interval):
        self.activated = False
        self.sound = "Beeeep"
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        # this runs forever
        while True:
            if self.activated:
                print(self.sound)
            else:
                print("(quiet)")
            sleep(self.interval)

    def on(self):
        self.activated = True

    def off(self):
        self.activated = False

    def set_beep(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound

def main():

    a1 = alarm(.5)
    a2 = alarm(.5)

    print("Waiting 3 secs")
    sleep(3)
    print("Turning on alarm1")
    a1.on()

    sleep(2)
    print("Turning on alarm2")
    a2.on()

    sleep(2)
    print("Turning off alarms")
    a1.off()
    a2.off()

    print("Waiting 10 seconds")
    sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```